# How can I append element to the DataFrame with this data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I add last element to DataFrame

```
...    a       b           c        d        e        f
2740   String  2017-11-20  1020.26  1018.38  1022.61  1017.50
2741   String  2017-11-21  1023.31  1034.49  1035.11  1022.66
2742   String  2017-11-22  1035.00  1035.96  1039.71  1031.43
```

to get DataFrame as shown below?

```
...    a       b           c        d        e        f
2740   String  2017-11-20  1020.26  1018.38  1022.61  1017.50
2741   String  2017-11-21  1023.31  1034.49  1035.11  1022.66
2742   String  2017-11-22  1035.00  1035.96  1039.71  1031.43
2743   String  2017-11-23  0        0        0        0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df.loc[2743,['a','b']]  = ('String','2017-11-23')
df = df.fillna(0)
df
```

Output:

```
           a           b        c        d        e        f
2740  String  2017-11-20  1020.26  1018.38  1022.61  1017.50
2741  String  2017-11-21  1023.31  1034.49  1035.11  1022.66
2742  String  2017-11-22  1035.00  1035.96  1039.71  1031.43
2743  String  2017-11-23     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00
```

Comment: I modified your solution `df.loc[df.last_valid_index()+1, ['a', 'b']] = ("string", datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`, what do you think?

Comment: @JohnSmith In that case you could do `df.loc[df.index[-1] + 1, ['a', 'b']] = ['string', df.b.iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)]` to the same effect.